# Fade in effect on hover using css?

Tags: html, css

I have read answers to similar questions to mine but cant quite get my head around how it works. i want a way where a box fades in slowly where an area is hovered over and disappears the same way, not abruptly.

in my code when the user hovers over a particular area a box should appear with instructions (and disappear when the area is not hovered over)

here is the html:

```
<div class="third">
        <label> Enter Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="pword1" class="iBox" id="pword1" onmouseout="HideToolTip()" onmouseover="ShowToolTip()" onkeyup="allFunctions()" placeholder="choose a password" autocomplete="off">
        <p id="tooltipbox" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden">Password must be between 8-16 characters, contain an uppercase, lowercase, number and special character</p>
    </div>
```

here is the css:

```
#tooltipbox{
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;

  transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
}
```

at the moment it is close to being perfect but it does not fade in and out slowly which is what i want. it just abruptly appears/disappears when the mouse is over or not. how can i get the desired fade effect?

p.s. i only want to do this in css not js
thanks

code for vincent:

```
   <div class="third">
            <label> Enter Password: </label>
            <input type="text" name="pword1" class="iBox" id="pword1" onmouseout="HideToolTip()" onmouseover="ShowToolTip()" onkeyup="allFunctions()" placeholder="choose a password" autocomplete="off">
            <div id="test">
            <p>Password must be between 8-16 characters, contain an uppercase, lowercase, number and special character</p>
            </div>
        </div>

#test p{
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;

}

#test p:hover {
    color:black;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this similar to what you want? EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/VV2ek/2578/

Comment: @Vincent That version is disappearing abruptly for me on Chrome.

Comment: @VincentBeltman ive change my code to look like yours. i will paste it now at the bottom of my question. it works apart from it is visible initially rather than hidden like yours???

Comment: yes and what Blake said, it appears smoothly disappears abruptly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking to animate the opacity, not the background.

Initialize the opacity to 0, setup animations:

```
opacity: 0;

-o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
```

Set opacity to 1 for a hover:

```
.third:hover #tooltipbox{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eypm4v5u/

Comment: mate, i have just realized a little error in this which is bugging me. basically i only want the hover to occur when you hover over the text area but at the moment when i hover over the text that says `Enter Password` it also comes up and there is some black space after the text area and hovering over that also brings it up. anyway just to make it come up when hovering over the area the user writes in? thanks bud

Comment: You would probably have to create another container to hold both the input and the tooltip. http://jsfiddle.net/eypm4v5u/2/

Answer (score 1):

This may be the effect you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/9jqrz813/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="third">
        <label> Enter Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="pword1" class="iBox" id="pword1" onmouseout="HideToolTip()" onmouseover="ShowToolTip()" onkeyup="allFunctions()" placeholder="choose a password" autocomplete="off">
        <p id="tooltipbox">Password must be between 8-16 characters, contain an uppercase, lowercase, number and special character</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#tooltipbox {
   padding: 10px;

    color: red;
  /* HOVER OFF */
   -webkit-transition: color 2s;
   -moz-transition: color 2s;
   -o-transition: color 2s;
   transition: color 2s;
}

#tooltipbox:hover {
   padding: 10px;

    color: white;
  /* HOVER ON */
   -webkit-transition: color 2s;
   -moz-transition: color 2s;
   -o-transition: color 2s;
   transition: color 2s;
}
```